# Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, sequelize.js, mean-stack

I am using the findAll method to search for all the users but it gives this error,
Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined.

user.js

```
var user = require("../../models/user");
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
var constants = require("../../config/constants");
var requestHelper = require("../../helpers/request");
var responseHelper = require("../../helpers/response");
var model = require("../../models");

 var main = {
    title: "Hello World",
    statusCode: constants.HTTP.CODES.SUCCESS
}

main.signup = function (req, res, next) {

    var postBody = requestHelper.parseBody(req.body); //requestHelper converts into json format
    var responseBody = {}; `

   if (postBody.name != null && postBody.password != null) {

    model.user.findAll().then(function (emp) { // finding user 

          //...........working......//

                 });
            }
        });
    }
}

  module.exports = main;
```

I have checked using console.log(model.user) it says undefined but cannot find out the problem causing it
Model of user.js

```
`'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var user = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return user;
};
```

`

Comment: Probably because `model.user` is `undefined`

Maybe you are referring to `user` which is imported first at the top of the file

Comment: yes it is referred to the user which is imported ... but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The "model.user" is not initialized. The possible ways to debug is to set an alert(or console.log) as

```
alert('model.user is : '+model.user);
```

or

```
console.log('model.user is : '+model.user);
```

Based on these alerts you will be able to debug which of these is undefined. If you are able to find out that it is undefined, then check the source for model to see if 'user' is defined properly. Do share the model source if the above suggestion does not work.

Comment: it still says undefined.I have added the model of user

Comment: Can you share the source content of model?